# I want to convert R code to Python using ifelse loop

Tags: r, python-3.x, if-statement

This is the following R code.

**mutate(Loan_Status_delinquency = ifelse(EOM_Delinq_Bucket %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4), "Yes", "No"))**

I want this to  be convert into Python

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
df['result'] = df.Loan_Status_delinquency.isin([1,2,3,4]).replace({ True : 'Yes', False : 'No'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['new_columm']] = df.Loan_Status_delinquency.apply(lambda x: "Yes" if x in [1,2,3,4] else "No")
```

Will add a column `new_column` onto your pandas dataframe `df`. In the future please have a go and we can look at your attempt - it'll mean you have to come here less often!